# How can I remove part of folder name

Tags: bash

I have list of folder names

```
file1xxx
file2xxx
file3xxx
```

I want to remove "xxx" from it's name.
I tried the following bash

```
for dirname in $(cat ${in}/all.txt); do # all.txt include the name of the folders in specific path ${in}
    [ -d "$dirname" ] || continue
    mv ${in}/$dirname ${in}/${dirname//.nii/}
done
```

but it didn't work!
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bash` you can do :

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do [[ -d $dir ]] && mv -i "$dir" "${dir%???}"; done <all.txt
```

this will read the file `all.txt` line by line and check if the directory represented by the line exists, if so then renaming will be done accordingly.

**EDIT :**

To remove only one character, make the [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) pattern `${dir%???}` as `${dir%?}`, the metacharacter `?` represents single character in `bash`. So :

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do [[ -d $dir ]] && mv -i "$dir" "${dir%?}"; done <all.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Kindly one more question. If I want to remove only the last charter "x" from the folder names to make it "file1xx,..."
how can I do that?

Comment: @MJA check m y edits

Comment: Please how can this code be used to remove the first letter?

Comment: @goro Do: `${dir#?}`